# Why ATMEGA328P U-TH doesn't answer to USBasp but work fine with Arduino as ISP?

Tags: arduino, atmega328p

I ordered ATMEGA328P AU from China recently but I got "ATMEGA328P U-TH". which seem super problematic.
I try to use USBasp to burn bootloader but it fail and show error message as shown.

```
avrdude: error: program enable: target doesn't answer. 1 
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
     Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
     this check.
```

which I believed many people face same situation as mine. Then I accidentally found the solution by using Arduino as ISP which successfully burn bootloader. After that I can use USBasp to upload sketch or burn bootloader.  I don't understand what happen here.
Note: I solder ATMEGA328P U-TH in SMD package to Arduino UNO clone.